# Auto focus editor when opening a file as preview from the left bar Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently when I click on a file on the Explorer view, on the left bar, the file that opens isn't focused. This used to be different, once you clicked the file, the open editor was focused right away, allowing me to, for example, do a cmnd+F to search in the file on the spot. Now, instead it opens the Explorer filter since the Explorer keeps the focus

I've been looking all around in the docs, the settings, internet, etc, and I couldn't find anything about it.

Is there a way to change this back? I know I could double-click the file to actually open it, instead of having it as a preview, and that way it would work, but I'd like to be able to get a focused preview right away when clicking the file, without the need to remember to focus the editor, which turns out I'm not good at